# Syntax error in complicated JOIN clause of SQL query through Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have 4 tables I need to join w/ the following fields that can be linked:

1. tblModels (TRADE_DATE, MODEL)
2. tblModelDef (MODEL, ASSET)
3. tblFutPx (TRADE_DATE, ASSET)
4. tblTA (TRADE_DATE, ASSET)

I want to "LEFT JOIN" the tblModels- i.e. I want to display all of the data for tblModels and show data for tblFutPx and tblTA when available for the corresponding [TRADE_DATE].  So the link is [TRADE_DATE] and [ASSET] for the relevant data, but I need to use tblModelDef as a bridge between tblModels and tblFutPx & tblTA.

I keep getting "Syntax error in JOIN operation" errors.

I've been trying to get this to work for way too long, but this is where I'm at.  I've tried simplifying the FROM clause to ensure the error is coming from it, and it is.

```
FROM ((tblModels INNER JOIN tblModelDef ON tblModels.[MODEL] = tblModelDef.[MODEL]) LEFT JOIN tblFutPx ON (tblModelDef.[ASSET] = tblFutPx.[ASSET]) AND (tblModels.[TRADE_DATE] = tblFutPx.[TRADE_DATE])) LEFT JOIN (tblTA ON (tblModels.[TRADE_DATE] = tblTA.[TRADE_DATE]) AND (tblModelDef.[ASSET] = tblTA.[ASSET]))
```

Comment: Exactly what are the relationships? 1 Model has many Asset? Each Trade_Date has many Asset?

Comment: Thank you for the help- Each MODEL has 1 ASSET intblModelDef.  There is one TRADE_DATE per MODEL in tblModels.  There is one TRADE_DATE per ASSET in tblFutPx and tblTA.  The key is to show ALL data for tblModels (which will be one record per TRADE_DATE/MODEL combo) and include the data from tblTA and tblFutPx when available for that TRADE_DATE/ASSET combo.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need multiple queries to accomplish. Built tables and used Query Builder to design query. Did not assign any primary keys, just set links to 'show all records from tblModels...'. Access used RIGHT JOIN.

Query1:

```
SELECT tblModelDef.Model, tblModelDef.Asset, tblModels.Trade_Date
FROM tblModelDef RIGHT JOIN tblModels ON tblModelDef.Model = tblModels.Model;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Query1.Model, tblFutPx.Trade_Date, tblFutPx.Asset, tblTA.Trade_Date, tblTA.Asset
FROM tblFutPx RIGHT JOIN (tblTA RIGHT JOIN Query1 ON (tblTA.Asset = Query1.Asset) AND (tblTA.Trade_Date = Query1.Trade_Date)) ON (tblFutPx.Asset = Query1.Asset) AND (tblFutPx.Trade_Date = Query1.Trade_Date);
```

All in one nested:

```
SELECT Query1.Model, tblFutPx.Trade_Date, tblFutPx.Asset, tblTA.Trade_Date, tblTA.Asset
FROM tblFutPx RIGHT JOIN (tblTA RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT tblModelDef.Model, tblModelDef.Asset, tblModels.Trade_Date
    FROM tblModelDef RIGHT JOIN tblModels ON tblModelDef.Model = tblModels.Model) AS Query1 
ON (tblTA.Asset = Query1.Asset) AND (tblTA.Trade_Date = Query1.Trade_Date)) ON (tblFutPx.Asset = Query1.Asset) AND (tblFutPx.Trade_Date = Query1.Trade_Date);
```

Comment: I've been trying desperately to adapt this, as I am pretty sure I understand the logic here (and it should work!).  I had to amend a bit to retrieve the appropriate fields.  This is where I am at now, but I keep getting a "No value given for one or more required parameters" error.

Comment: `SELECT tblFutPx.[CLOSE_C], Query1.[PX_ACT_R], tblTA.[RSI] FROM tblFutPx RIGHT JOIN (tblTA RIGHT JOIN (SELECT tblModels.[PX_ACT_R], tblModels.[TRADE_DATE], tblModelDef.[ASSET] FROM tblModelDef INNER JOIN tblModels ON tblModels.[MODEL] = tblModelDef.[MODEL]) AS Query1 ON (tblTA.[ASSET] = Query1.[ASSET]) AND (tblTA.[TRADE_DATE] = Query1.[TRADE_DATE])) ON (tblFutPx.[ASSET] = Query1.[ASSET]) AND (tblFutPx.[TRADE_DATE] = Query1.[TRADE_DATE]) WHERE Query1.[TRADE_DATE] BETWEEN #1/1/2012# AND #1/21/2019# AND Query1.[MODEL] = 'CPE_R_SA_M' ORDER BY Query1.[TRADE_DATE] ASC`

Comment: Got it!  I wasn't including tblModels.[MODEL] in the SELECT clause of the nested Query1, and then I was trying to do a WHERE filter on it later.  This worked now- thank you again for the help!